# Python-I need my program to count how many times each outcome of 2 dice being rolled has happened. (2-12 are the possible outcomes)

Tags: python, dice

```
import random

num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))
results = int()

if num_rolls >= 1:
    for i in range(num_rolls):
        die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        roll_total = die1 + die2
        results =+ 1
    print('Roll %d is %d (%d + %d)' % (i, roll_total, die1, die2))       
    for j in range(results):
        print('\nDice roll statistics:')
        print('%ds:'% roll_total, results)
```

Output should be like:

Roll 1 is 6 (3 + 3)

Roll 2 is 7 (3 + 4)

Roll 3 is 6 (4 + 2)

Roll 4 is 5 (2 + 3)

Dice roll statistics:

6s: 1

7s: 2

6s: 3

5s: 4

Comment: This is my result: 

Enter number of rolls:
Roll 5 is 8 (4 + 4)

Dice roll statistics:
8s: 1


and I assume the expected result is something like:


Enter number of rolls:
Roll 0 is int (int+int)
Roll 1 is int (int+int)
Roll 2 is int (int+int)
Roll 3 is int (int+int)
Roll 4 is int (int+int)
Roll 5 is 8 (4 + 4)

Dice roll statistics:
1s: int
2s: int
3s: int
4s: int
5s: int
6s: int
7s: int
8s: 1
9s: int
10s: int
11s: int
12s: int

Comment: Information critical to the question must be edited into the question, not relegated to a comment.

Comment: PS I'd rename `results` to `nrolls` to emphasize what it does. (`results` is a generic name, it could equally refer to counting either the individual rolls, or the total, or the number of rolls, or indeed the average, standard deviation, etc.).

Comment: I don't have enough character to enter the results how they should look. Keeps telling me I am over the given amount of characters

Comment: it keeps bsing me when I am aediting the question so here is what the program wants me to do:
Calculates the number of times the sum of the randomly rolled dice equals each possible value from 2 to 12.

Comment: They put that output on there and it is not what I am looking for at all. I don't know why that happened because I did not approve that lol. this is a s$#@ show

Comment: If it says you're out of characters, you're adding a comment and not editing the post. Click the word "Edit" between the question text and the comments list to add important information to the question (or remove what someone else added if it's not what you mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the next output:

```py
Enter number of rolls:
11
Roll 1 is 6 (2 + 4)
Roll 2 is 7 (2 + 5)
Roll 3 is 6 (4 + 2)
Roll 4 is 3 (1 + 2)
Roll 5 is 6 (3 + 3)
Roll 6 is 2 (1 + 1)
Roll 7 is 9 (6 + 3)
Roll 8 is 5 (3 + 2)
Roll 9 is 6 (5 + 1)
Roll 10 is 5 (3 + 2)
Roll 11 is 7 (4 + 3)

Dice roll statistics:
6s: 4
7s: 2
3s: 1
2s: 1
9s: 1
5s: 2
```

You can do

```py
import random

num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))
statistics = []
helper = 0

if num_rolls >= 1:
    for i in range(1,num_rolls+1):
        die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        roll_total = die1 + die2
        print('Roll %d is %d (%d + %d)' % (i, roll_total, die1, die2))
        stat = '%ds:'% roll_total
        final = [stat,1]
        if len(statistics) > 0:
            for i in statistics:
                if stat in i:
                    i[1] += 1
                    helper = 1
                    break
            if helper == 0:
                statistics.append(final)
            helper = 0
        else:
            statistics.append(final)
 
print('\nDice roll statistics:')
for i in statistics:
    print(*i)
```

Comment: Thanks you. So close but something isn't counting up the results of each roll correctly.

Comment: works perfect for me, what results are you getting?

Comment: In your example, the dice roll statistics are stating which roll that result happened when I am looking for how many times that roll happened in the amount of rolls I told the program to do. I may not have explained the question or this answer properly.

Comment: ohh you want it to say how many times that same number appeared?

Comment: yes lol sorry for the confusion. I did not want them to add that output at the bottom of my problem

Comment: i modified my answer to match your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Because `roll_total = die1 + die2` keeps overwriting `roll_total` on every iteration.

You want to do `roll_total += (die1 + die2)`.

(PS: debugging tip, if you used a `print(roll_total)` inside your for-loop you'd likely catch this)

Comment: it is hard to understand the question but it seems to me that the OP wants to append results to the list and then print them out, but there is no clarification

Comment: @Matiiss: no they initialize `roll_total = 0` to an integer not an empty list (also it's called 'total' not 'roll_results' or 'rolls')

Comment: True but the comment OP posted asks for clarification because it seems like OP wants to print mulitple something but it is not clear what exactly OP wants (at least not to me entirely)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to print the `roll_total` for each roll, store the value of each `roll_total` as a list in `results`.

```
import random

num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))
results = []

if num_rolls >= 1:
    for i in range(num_rolls):
        die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        roll_total = die1 + die2
        results.append(roll_total)
    print('Roll %d is %d (%d + %d)' % (i, roll_total, die1, die2))       
    print('\nDice roll statistics:')
    for j in range(len(results)):
        print(f'{j+1}: {results[j]}')
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter number of rolls:
6
Roll 5 is 9 (3 + 6)

Dice roll statistics:
1: 7
2: 7
3: 7
4: 9
5: 6
6: 9
```